# Analyzing high CPU usage in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cpu

I have a production system running on three tomcat servers. Suddenly one of my tomcat server is showing 100% CPU usage which I have taken out of pool.

Can any one guide on how can I start to debug this issue? Any tools / utilities?

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd try is to get a thread dump and see what's running.

From [this article](http://java.sys-con.com/node/1611555):

> Generating Java Thread Dumps Thread Dump is generated by sending a
>   SIGQUIT signal to the JVM process. There are different ways of sending
>   this signal to the process.
>
> In Unix, use "kill -3 " where pid is the Process ID of the JVM.
>
> In Windows, press CTRL+BREAK on the window where the JVM is running

This will at least show you which threads in your applications are running, and give you a basic indication as to what's going on. [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) will provide anothe rmeans of getting this info, and is perhaps easier for server processes disconnected from the console.

A more detailed report can be obtained by using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to report on thread/CPU + memory usage.

Comment: The Tomcat FAQ has a page about generating thread dumps: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_obtain_a_thread_dump_of_my_running_webapp_.3F

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [JTop](http://lsd.luminis.nl/top-threads-plugin-for-jconsole/), it's like unix `top` but for threads within a JVM.